# SlidingMenu and Maven

Tags: java, android, maven, slidingmenu

When trying to add [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) as a dependecy like below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.slidingmenu</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

I get an error saying it cannot find SlidingMenu. Is the dependency correct? I haven't found it defined anywhere.

Comment: post the complete error message...

Comment: It sounds like it is not in a public repository. You can download it manually and use the `mvn install:install-file` command to put it into your local repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two issues.

1. This dependency does not appear to be available in the Central repository, which means that Maven won't be able to automatically download it. You'll need to download and build the project manually, then install in your local repository using the `install` plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html
2. The `artifactId` and `type` elements are incorrect. Looking at the project link, the artifact ID is `slidingmenu`, and the type should be `apklib`. Note that I haven't looked very deeply; there may be other modules in that project.

Also, Maven may or may not be able to properly combine the `apklib` dependency type. I haven't used Maven to build Android, so don't know what the configuration is, but would suspect it requires some use of the assembly plugin.